# What is the difference between the three ways of applying constraints to a template?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I just learned that C++20 provides three ways of applying constraints to a template:

- Requires Clause
- Trailing Requires Clause
- Constrained Template Parameter

I successfully used constrained template parameters and I tend to prefer that syntax. Still I wonder why there are **three** ways defined in the standard.

Are there fundamental technical differences? Do these flavors have unique advantages or disadvantages (other than syntactical appearance)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no *technical* differences.

```
// (1)
void foo(Concept auto&& x);
```

means exactly the same thing as:

```
// (2)
template <Concept T>
void foo(T&& x);
```

means exactly the same thing as:

```
// (3)
template <typename T> requires Concept<T>
void foo(T&& x);
```

means exactly the same thing as:

```
// (4)
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& x) requires Concept<T>;
```

... but just pick one and use it consistently for the same function (can't declare with one syntax and define with another).

And there are reasons for each of them to exist - (1) is shorter than (2) but (2) gives you the name of the type - which you can then use in other places. (2) is shorter than (3) and (4), but (3) and (4) are more general and allow more kinds of constraints. (3) and (4) seem the same, but (4) is necessary for member functions of class templates and also gives you access to parameter names.

Comment: I didn't know about (1). When using that syntax, can the function de defined in the .cpp file or do I need to define it in the header like a template function?

Comment: @Silicomancer It's not _like_ a function template, it _is_ a function template. These are all exactly the same, same behavior, same rules.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was not sure about that since "template" is omitted for (1).

Comment: Could you maybe give examples for what you meant with "allow more kinds of constraints"?

Comment: @Silicomancer Any boolean condition, any constraint on a non-type template parameter, a _requires-expression_, ...

Comment: Even though they mean the same thing, the way you write it is significant - you can't mix and match for the same function template.

Comment: @T.C. You can't mix? So a template with a constrained template parameter can't have a requires clause?

Comment: @Silicomancer No, you can mix within a declaration. You just can't declare a function template using one syntax and then define it using a different syntax.