# Requires clause positioning in C++20 function templates

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

In C++20, you can write a constrained function template in a couple of different ways:

```
template <typename T>
concept Fooable = true;

template <typename T>
    requires Fooable<T>
void do_something(T&); // (1)

template <typename T>
void do_something(T&) requires Fooable<T>; // (2)
```

According to the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875211/what-is-the-difference-between-the-three-ways-of-applying-constraints-to-a-templ), these two forms are equivalent (which has always been my understanding).

However, I notice that GCC 12.1 considers (1) and (2) to be two different functions, rather than (2) being a redeclaration: it's possible to provide definitions for both, and attempting to call `do_something()` is then ambiguous ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/WjTn677nj)).

- Is GCC correct, and these are two different functions?
- If so, are there any technical differences in meaning between the two styles?

EDIT:

- As pointed out in the comments, the linked questions states that a function template declaration and definition must use the same "requires style". What is the reason for this restriction?

(I vaguely recall from the Concepts TS days that requirements underwent "normalisation" to decide when they were equivalent -- I guess this is no longer the case in C++20?)

Comment: The accepted answer on that question also says "can't declare with one syntax and define with another" - Which is perhaps not explicit, but certainly says it declares different functions.

Comment: Okay, but why is that the case?

Comment: The non-language lawyer answer is that the first can only apply to template parameter lists, while the second to any function (which may not be templates). Applying the second form to a non-template would happen for instance if we disable a (non-template) member function of a class template. For the LL rabbit hole, someone will come along soon, I'm sure.

Comment: Sure, but the rule could have been something like, "form (1) gets interpreted as if you have written it in form (2)" (which I vaguely recall was the case in the Concepts TS days?). That's why I was kinda surprised that GCC allows this overloading.

Comment: It could, but it wasn't. Probably for the same reasons abbreviated templates are not just "rewritten" regular templates, there's no equivalency there either. And I'd wager all of it is likely to play nice with ODR paragraphs that require the same definition down to the token sequence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wording in this area has moved around a bit. In C++20, we had this rule in [[temp.over.link]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.over.link#7):

> 7. Two function templates are equivalent if they are declared in the same scope, have the same name, have equivalent template-heads, and have return types, parameter lists, and trailing requires-clauses (if any) that are equivalent using the rules described above to compare expressions involving template parameters. Two function templates are functionally equivalent if they are declared in the same scope, have the same name, accept and are satisfied by the same set of template argument lists, and have return types and parameter lists that are functionally equivalent using the rules described above to compare expressions involving template parameters. If the validity or meaning of the program depends on whether two constructs are equivalent, and they are functionally equivalent but not equivalent, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.
> 8. [Note 7: This rule guarantees that equivalent declarations will be linked with one another, while not requiring implementations to use heroic efforts to guarantee that functionally equivalent declarations will be treated as distinct.
>
> ```cpp
> // guaranteed to be the same
> template <int I> void f(A<I>, A<I+10>);
> template <int I> void f(A<I>, A<I+10>);
>
> // guaranteed to be different
> template <int I> void f(A<I>, A<I+10>);
> template <int I> void f(A<I>, A<I+11>);
>
> // ill-formed, no diagnostic required
> template <int I> void f(A<I>, A<I+10>);
> template <int I> void f(A<I>, A<I+1+2+3+4>);
> ```
>
> -*end note*]

In your example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
    requires Fooable<T>
void do_something(T&); // (1)

template <typename T>
void do_something(T&) requires Fooable<T>; // (2)
```

These are functionally equivalent (they have the same constraints, basically) but not equivalent (they have different template-heads - the requires clause after the template parameters is part of the template-head), which makes this ill-formed no diagnostic required. In practice, because they're not *equivalent*, they're different overloads - but because they're functionally equivalent, any attempt to call would be ambiguous between them.

As I point out in the other answer, these have the same meaning - it's just that you have to stick with one form for the declaration and the definition if you split them.

---

The *current* wording, after Davis Herring's omnibus paper [P1787](https://wg21.link/p1787), involves going up to [[basic.scope.scope]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#4.3):

> Two declarations correspond if they (re)introduce the same name, both declare constructors, or both declare destructors, unless [...] each declares a function or function template, except when [...] both declare function templates with equivalent non-object-parameter-type-lists, return types (if any), template-heads, and trailing requires-clauses (if any), and, if both are non-static members, they have corresponding object parameters.

This makes the two `do_something`s *not correspond*, which makes them different function templates. We don't run into the new functionally equivalent but not equivalent rule (so we're not ill-formed, no diagnostic required), but we just have two function templates that are necessarily ambiguous in all cases. So... not the most useful thing in the world.

Comment: wow, that is something I had no idea was a thing. The reasoning kinda makes sense after reading it - The no diagnostic required means I do have a few lines of code in some projects to look into now, though :(

Comment: Thanks Barry! I thought there was a re-write rule in place, and indeed in the Concepts TS this was a redeclaration (https://godbolt.org/z/W1a63cP47). Do you know when/why this was changed?

Comment: @TristanBrindle Yeah (https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4641.pdf, search for temp.over.link). Probably because it just adds more work to the compiler to check but doesn't actually add any value? I don't know for sure, I can ask Andrew.

Comment: @Barry I don't know how you find these references so quickly! IFNDR does seem kinda harsh though

Comment: Which rule states that the two function templates in question are functionally equivalent? [temp.over.link]/6 says that two *template-heads* are functionally equivalent if they accept and are satisfied by the same set of template argument lists. In the case of (2), is it correct to say that the *template-head* does not accept a `T` that is not `Fooable`? The constraint in that case is not part of the *template-head*.

Comment: @BrianBi Now this rule might have moved over into the correspond wording (https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#4.3)

Comment: @TristanBrindle One problem here btw is that like `template <class T> requires meow<T>(v) void f(T v)` and `template <class T> void f(T v) requires meow<T>(v)` could actually mean different things, despite being token for token equivalent (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062387/2069064))

Comment: [basic.scope.scope]/4.3 would not seem to support the conclusion that the program is ill-formed NDR. The non-object-parameter-type-lists and return types are equivalent. The *template-heads* are neither equivalent nor functionally equivalent since one of them is constrained and the other is not. The trailing *requires-clauses* are neither equivalent nor functionally equivalent since one is present and the other is not. These four criteria are considered separately.

Comment: @BrianBi The wording here has changed a lot and it's hard to keep track. Pre-Davis' paper, the functionally equivalent wording applied. Now it seems to just miss this case. I don't think it super matters, since ultimately these two are not _equivalent_ - but since they're satisfied by the same types they're "functionally equivalent"-ish, so writing it both ways doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't really matter, but for the purposes of this question, it does affect the answer. Simply declaring (1) and (2) in the same translation unit does not make the program IFNDR. The program becomes IF if an attempt is made to call `do_something`, since overload resolution will never succeed.

Comment: I suspect the intent is (still) to have these be IFNDR, and that the various equivalencies should be considered together (if only because you can’t establish equivalence of components of a template independently of its *template-head*).  An issue might be in order.