# Changing position of C++20 "requires clause" gives different results

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts, spaceship-operator

Consider the following type `MyType` together with a SFINAE-style detection whether some type `U` is `MyType` or not:

```
template <class T>
struct MyType {
    using value_type = T;
    static constexpr bool is_my_type = true;
    value_type value{};
};


// A constexpr function returning true if <U> is NOT "MyType".
template <class U>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<U::is_my_type, bool> IsNotMyType(U const *) {
    return false;
}

template <class>
constexpr bool IsNotMyType(...) {
    return true;
}
```

Then I define an equality operator (which is necessary for reproduction) and two spaceship operators, one for a comparison of `MyType<T>` with `MyType<U>`, and one for a comparison of `MyType<T>` with some type `U` which is **not** a `MyType`:

```
// Necessary for reproduction
template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(MyType<T> const & lhs, MyType<U> const & rhs) {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value;
}


template <class T, class U>
std::compare_three_way_result_t<
    typename MyType<T>::value_type,
    typename MyType<U>::value_type> 
  operator<=>(MyType<T> const & lhs, MyType<U> const & rhs)
  requires(
    std::three_way_comparable_with<typename MyType<T>::value_type, typename MyType<U>::value_type>)
{
    return lhs.value <=> rhs.value;
}


template <class T, class U>
std::compare_three_way_result_t<typename MyType<T>::value_type, U> 
  operator<=>(MyType<T> const & lhs, U const & rhs)
  // Problematic requires clause
  requires(
    IsNotMyType<U>(nullptr) &&
    std::three_way_comparable_with<typename MyType<T>::value_type, U>)
{
    return lhs.value <=> rhs;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main(){
    MyType<int> m;
    [[maybe_unused]] auto t = m <=> m;
}
```

Live example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6qK8d43dM).
gcc and MSVC compile this without issue with C++20, but Clang runs into a `"fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth"` (both with libstdc++ and libc++):

```
test.cc:41:6: fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 1024
std::compare_three_way_result_t<typename MyType<T>::value_type, U>
     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/concepts:306:10: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator<=>' [with T = int, U = remove_reference_t<MyType<int>>]
          { __t <  __u } -> __boolean_testable;
                ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/concepts:306:6: note: in instantiation of requirement here
          { __t <  __u } -> __boolean_testable;
            ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/concepts:304:4: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
        = requires(const remove_reference_t<_Tp>& __t,
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/compare:420:10: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept '__partially_ordered_with<MyType<int>, MyType<int>>' requested here
      && __detail::__partially_ordered_with<_Tp, _Tp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/compare:420:10: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
      && __detail::__partially_ordered_with<_Tp, _Tp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/compare:430:10: note: (skipping 2039 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
      && three_way_comparable<_Up, _Cat>
         ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/compare:420:10: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
      && __detail::__partially_ordered_with<_Tp, _Tp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/compare:430:10: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept 'three_way_comparable<MyType<int>, std::partial_ordering>' requested here
      && three_way_comparable<_Up, _Cat>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/compare:430:10: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
      && three_way_comparable<_Up, _Cat>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:46:5: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept 'three_way_comparable_with<int, MyType<int>, std::partial_ordering>' requested here
    std::three_way_comparable_with<typename MyType<T>::value_type, U>)
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:54:33: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator<=>' [with T = int, U = MyType<int>]
    [[maybe_unused ]]auto t = m <=> m;
```

If I move the trailing `requires` clause of the second `operator<=>` to before the return value, Clang is happy (full example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9Exsr5oWT)):

```
template <class T, class U>
  // Problematic requires clause
  requires(
    IsNotMyType<U>(nullptr) &&
    std::three_way_comparable_with<typename MyType<T>::value_type, U>)
std::compare_three_way_result_t<typename MyType<T>::value_type, U> 
  operator<=>(MyType<T> const & lhs, U const & rhs)
{
    return lhs.value <=> rhs;
}
```

From what I understood so far, e.g. from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72263705/3740047), the position of the `requires` clause should not matter, but apparently Clang thinks differently. Who is right? Are there actually cases according to the standard where a different position of the `requires` clause can cause functional differences?

Comment: clang is known to sometimes instantiate templates a bit early, and thus turn a potential sfinae case into a hard error. This might be one of those cases.

Comment: Is the type you check against meant to be a base class? If it is not, the `requires` clause is pretty much redundant. Partial ordering will already favor the first spaceship overload above a more generic one.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes, in the original code, `MyType` is derived from some base class, and the check is whether I have any type derived from that base class or the base class itself. I just stripped it down as far as I could while reproducing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> test.cc:41:6: fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 1024

Regardless of whether this is legal C++ or not (and it is), this kind of error represents either a compiler bug or a compiler limitation. This is doubly obvious when you see how easy it is to fix:

```
#include <compare>

template <class T>
struct MyType {
    using value_type = T;
    static constexpr bool is_my_type = true;
    value_type value{};
};

template<typename T>
concept IsMyType = T::is_my_type;


// Necessary for reproduction
template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(MyType<T> const & lhs, MyType<U> const & rhs) {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value;
}


template <class T, class U>
  std::compare_three_way_result_t<
    typename MyType<T>::value_type,
    typename MyType<U>::value_type> operator<=>(MyType<T> const & lhs, MyType<U> const & rhs)
  requires(
    std::three_way_comparable_with<typename MyType<T>::value_type, typename MyType<U>::value_type>)

{
    return lhs.value <=> rhs.value;
}


template <class T, class U>
std::compare_three_way_result_t<typename MyType<T>::value_type, U> 
  operator<=>(MyType<T> const & lhs, U const & rhs)
  // Problematic requires clause
  requires(
    !IsMyType<U> &&
    std::three_way_comparable_with<typename MyType<T>::value_type, U>)
{
    return lhs.value <=> rhs;
}
```

Take your `constexpr` function and turn it into a `concept`, and voila: it's fixed. It's also better code, because seriously: stop using old bad SFINAE in C++20.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that a modern approach would be to use a concept for `IsMyType`. However, this comes from a C++17 library where I am implementing the threeway comparison operator in case it is compiled with C++20, and the SFINAE version is also used for `operator<` etc. Nevertheless, thanks for confirming that it is indeed a clang bug, and that indeed the position of the `requires` clause does not matter according to the standard.

Comment: @Sedenion : N.b. your code compiles fine using Clang trunk